# Calling a function inside another function in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have the function `removeItem`, which deletes an item from my list:

```
  removeItem(item, i) {
    this.produto.splice(i, 1);
    this.campo_total = Number(this.campo_total) - Number(item.valor);
  }
```

I created the `comparar` function that compares the value of the products, and if it has any value less than the default, it cannot be created and is deleted from the list.

```
 comparar(item, i) {

        if (this.comparador < this.campo_total) {
         removeItem(); //here the function r calling
          alert("ERROR: cannot register this item");
        }
      }
```

I tried calling this function but it does not work. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Those functions both live inside the same class right? Then you need `this`, so `this.removeItem(item, i);`.

Edit: You also need to pass the arguments the *removeItem* function expects.

Comment: i do this and bring me the error: cannot read property 'valid' of undefined

Comment: The code you posted doesn't contain any property valid. Where does the console say valid cannot be found?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'valor' of undefined
    at Dados2Page.webpackJsonp.102.Dados2Page.removeItem (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:174:67)
    at Dados2Page.webpackJsonp.102.Dados2Page.comparar (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:179:18)

Comment: in comparer you are missing the arguments in your call of removeItem. See my updated answer.